# POST request to Instagram API using fetch(), throws Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, instagram-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I'm using `fetch` to retrieve data from Instagram API for **authorization**

Need **access token** in response to the request.

But, got error : 
`{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "You must provide a client_id"}`

```
const url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

let fetchData = {
            method: 'POST', 
            body: JSON.stringify({
              'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
              'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:3000/',
              'code':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            })
}

fetch(url, fetchData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response, "::response")
          return response.json();
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error," :: ERROR");
          return error;
        });
```

Comment: The Instagram API requires you to add the data in the URL as query parameters, like: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code` See here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: @Miguel,  As i'm using Server-side (Explicit) Flow.. i got that error! or Pls, Suggest that Should I use client(implicit) Flow as u commented above for react ? ..Thanks

Comment: In Server-side flow you have to use the URL like that. I quote: "Server-side (Explicit) Flow. Using the server-side flow is quite easy. Simply follow these steps: Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL
`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`

Comment: So, should i use the url in `fetch(url).then(...)` ? @Miguel

Comment: The docs say you have to do that first, yes, and then do another fetch. But you have to use a public redirect_uri hook in order ot receive the code. I recommend you to read through the Instagram API docs and rewrite your code once you fully understand the authorization flow.

Comment: Can't use Server side(Explicit) because i'm using react... &  The (Implicit) way working just fine.. Thanks . @Miguel

Comment: Great that you got it sorted out.